# Is there a way to persist a static table in Apache Flink

Tags: java, apache-flink

Currently, I am trying to deal with the ETL with Apache Flink. In the Project, there are several procedures need to query a dimension table to translate from `CityName` to `CityID`. The project Structure like below:

```
Project---------------------
       |
       ---- Company ETL (CityName column map to CityId)
       |
       ---- Employee ETL (CityName column map to CityId)
```

At present, for each stream, our method is call a jdbc query action on MySQL where dimension table located. This is not a effective way, I would like to ask is there a method that can keep the dimension table content in Flink internally and able to be used project-wide.

Comment: Are you wanting to use Flink's batch or streaming API? How large is this translation table, and how often does it change?

Comment: I am using the Streaming API to transfer data. The translation table is 10,000 records, normally the data modified monthly. Currently, I just use a java final static map to store the data from translation table. @alpinegizmo

Answer (score 0):

That sounds reasonable if you don't mind restarting your application when the translation table needs updating. But if you are looking for an alternative, you could stream in the translation table, along with updates, and use a `RichCoMap` or `RichCoFlatMap` to do to the translation. You would store the translation table as [state managed by Flink](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/stream/state.html). From Flink's perspective the translation table might be one chunk of monolithic `ValueState`, or in Flink 1.3 you could use `MapState` ([docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/stream/state.html#using-managed-keyed-state)).